# Running a method/function for a specified time

Tags: java, function, time

I'm looking for a easy way to execute a method/function for specified time in java. Something that would be like this:

```
for(3 secs){
   x();
}
```

The way should be easy to implement AND should have a good performance aswell.

Comment: What happen if x() takes 4 seconds?

Comment: if you're looking to periodically execute a task you can use the good ol' Timer class.

Comment: Do you want to execute x() repeatedly for 3 secs, OR wait for x to return, for 3 secs and then exit the block?

Comment: execute x() repeatedly. And I'm sure that the function won't take longer than the given time in my program.

Answer (score 4):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <= 3000){
  x();
}
```

+1 for Aaron's answer, with using `long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000` instead, moving the addition / subtraction outside of the loop, leaving only the comparison for efficiency / performance.

Note however, that once you enter x(), and if x() takes a while to run, the overall loop may run for longer than your desired time. If x() is length, you may want to add checks for the stop condition within it as well.

Comment: Never mind, this one is the same as mine and more efficient. I am deleting mine now.

Comment: Yes. I was also just about to post mine when I saw that the answer was already there.

Comment: How may times method x() will be executed? OP says **Running a method/function for a specified time**. Not number of times,I guess.

Comment: @AVD - but yet, the OP used a for loop for the example.  I also somewhat accounted for this in my answer.  Best we can do without further clarification from the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had the same way implemeted yet. But are you sure it's really accurate? For example, im currently using 600ms and I'm not really sure if it runs fine.

Comment: This will execute `x()` repeatedly, and ensure that no further executions start beyond the configured time.  However, as mentioned above in the answer, if `x()` take any significant amount of time, you may need to add additional checks within `x()` to allow it to return prematurely if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do

```
long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+3000;
while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= finishTime){
  x();
}
```

to move the arithmetic outside the loop, for efficiency/performance

Answer (score 1):

```
void run ( Runnable task , long milliseconds ) throws Exception
{
       new Thread ( )
       {
              public void run ( ) 
              {
                     while ( true )
                     {
                              task . run ( ) ;
                     }
              }
       } . start ( ) ;
       Thread . sleep ( milliseconds ) ;
       System . exit ( 0 ) ;
}
```

This will work even if the task takes longer than the time alloted.